# Creating a Data Frame with unknown size in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a data frame that I do not know the size of. Is there a way to create a data frame that adapts to your variables?

Am I able to do something like this?

```
df <- function(n){
x <- numeric(0)
y <- numeric(0)
z <- numeric(0)
i <- 0
repeat{
 x[i] <- value1(...)
 y[i] <- value2(...)
 z[i] <- value3(...)
 i < i + 1
if(i >= n){
 break
}
}
df <- data.frame(val1 = x, val2 = y, val3 = z)
}
```

For this sake lets assume that value1(), value2(), and value3() just return some numeric value.

Comment: You can create a dummy data frame like this: `n <- 10; df <- data.frame(x=numeric(n), y=character(n), z=logical(n))`. I don't know what you aim for...

Comment: Data frames don't have a static size. For example, `rbind()` or `cbind()` will always expand the size of your data frame. Though perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I guess you should know the size. Otherwise how is it possible to 'break' or your function will throw an error when `n` is not specified. And `rbind()` would work easily with a data frame with NULL elements (`data.frame(val1 = numeric(0), ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this way:

initialaize your data frame as empty using empty vectors:

```
df <- data.frame(val1=value1(),
                 val2=value2(), 
                 val3=value3())
```